# How to convert date to timestamp in PHP?

Tags: php, date, timestamp

How do I get timestamp from e.g. `22-09-2008`?

Answer (score 653):

*This method works on **both** Windows and Unix **and** is **time-zone** aware, which is probably what you want if you work with [dates](https://unix4lyfe.org/time/).*

If you don't care about timezone, or want to use the time zone your server uses:

```
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i:s', '22-09-2008 00:00:00');
if ($d === false) {
    die("Incorrect date string");
} else {
    echo $d->getTimestamp();
}
```

**1222093324** <sub>(This will differ depending on your server time zone...)</sub>

If you want to specify in which time zone, here EST. (Same as New York.)

```
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat(
    'd-m-Y H:i:s',
    '22-09-2008 00:00:00',
    new DateTimeZone('EST')
);

if ($d === false) {
    die("Incorrect date string");
} else {
    echo $d->getTimestamp();
}
```

**1222093305**

Or if you want to use [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). (Same as "[GMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time)".)

```
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat(
    'd-m-Y H:i:s',
    '22-09-2008 00:00:00',
    new DateTimeZone('UTC')
);

if ($d === false) {
    die("Incorrect date string");
} else {
    echo $d->getTimestamp();
}
```

**1222093289**

Regardless, it's always a good starting point to be strict when parsing strings into structured data. It can save awkward debugging in the future. Therefore I recommend to always specify date format.

Comment: A completely valid answer, but I'm surprised that Armin Ronacher's answer hasn't matched it in upvotes -- ambiguity is ALWAYS bad.

Comment: @Devner Well, it seems, on my server, that format isn't supported. Maybe it's different with yours.

Comment: Beware `strtotime('2012')` might result in a timestamp of today and time 20:12

Comment: This solution can lead to an unexpected behavior. Those who use PHP 5.3+ should adopt [Prof. Falken answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19320524/636561), in which one has full control over the date format.

Comment: @LucaFagioli It seems Prof.Falken, desperate to see that answer with so many upvotes,  updated it and included his own science.

Answer (score 189):

There is also [`strptime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php) which expects exactly one format:

```
$a = strptime('22-09-2008', '%d-%m-%Y');
$timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $a['tm_mon']+1, $a['tm_mday'], $a['tm_year']+1900);
```

### Warnings:

- This function is not implemented on Windows
- This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 8.1.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged.

Comment: it should be tm_mon instead of tm_month and tm_mday instead of tm_day

Comment: Beware, strptime function is not available on Windows.

Comment: Those on Windows and PHP 5.3.0+, consider using `date_parse_from_format` instead of `strptime`.

Comment: ... because `strptime` is not implemented in Windows platforms.

Comment: Since this is a highly voted answer, will you consider editing it to an answer which works on PHP for Windows as well as unixen? And IMHO ideally it should mention timezones.

Comment: Also, since PHP 5.3 https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php is recommended instead.

Answer (score 136):

With [`DateTime` API](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php):

```
$dateTime = new DateTime('2008-09-22'); 
echo $dateTime->format('U'); 

// or 

$date = new DateTime('2008-09-22');
echo $date->getTimestamp();
```

The same with the procedural API:

```
$date = date_create('2008-09-22');
echo date_format($date, 'U');

// or

$date = date_create('2008-09-22');
echo date_timestamp_get($date);
```

If the above fails because you are using a [unsupported format](http://www.php.net/manual/de/datetime.formats.php), you can use

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('!d-m-Y', '22-09-2008');
echo $dateTime->format('U'); 

// or

$date = date_parse_from_format('!d-m-Y', '22-09-2008');
echo date_format($date, 'U');
```

Note that if you do not set the `!`, the time portion will be set to current time, which is different from the first four which will use midnight when you omit the time.

Yet another alternative is to use the [`IntlDateFormatter`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php) API:

```
$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
    'en_US',
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    'GMT',
    IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN,
    'dd-MM-yyyy'
);
echo $formatter->parse('22-09-2008');
```

Unless you are working with localized date strings, the easier choice is likely DateTime.

Comment: I'd recommend this over my answer nowadays.

Comment: Arggg.  !  Don't forget the `!`  My date based timestamp was changing on each refresh and driving me mad - because DateTime was helpfully adding the current time without asking or being told.  Grrr.

Comment: I want to add that I recommend against ambiguous date parsing, and that the date format should be given explicitly when parsing date strings.

Answer (score 116):

Be careful with functions like `strtotime()` that try to "guess" what you mean (it doesn't guess of course, the [rules are here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113829/date-to-timestamp-php#113871)).

Indeed `22-09-2008` will be parsed as *22 September 2008*, as it is the only reasonable thing.

How will `08-09-2008` be parsed? Probably *09 August 2008*.

What about `2008-09-50`? Some versions of PHP parse this as *20 October 2008*.

So, if you are sure your input is in `DD-MM-YYYY` format, it's better to use the solution offered by [@Armin Ronacher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113829/date-to-timestamp-php#113871).

Comment: Valid concern. I guess strtotime() relies in your locale.

Comment: Note: on most non-english speaking countries, the format is `dd-mm-yyyy`, not `mm-dd-yyyy`.

Comment: @CamiloMartin Most non-english spoken countries use the first format you stated but the DB usually store the date in `YYYY-mm-dd` The conversion happens only to display to the users

Comment: @DannyG just looked at [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html) and it seems you're right if by DB you mean MySQL. But it does seem ridiculous to do this...

Answer (score 65):

*This method works on **both** Windows and Unix **and** is **time-zone** aware, which is probably what you want if you work with [dates](https://unix4lyfe.org/time/).*

If you don't care about timezone, or want to use the time zone your server uses:

```
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i:s', '22-09-2008 00:00:00');
if ($d === false) {
    die("Incorrect date string");
} else {
    echo $d->getTimestamp();
}
```

**1222093324** <sub>(This will differ depending on your server time zone...)</sub>

If you want to specify in which time zone, here EST. (Same as New York.)

```
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat(
    'd-m-Y H:i:s',
    '22-09-2008 00:00:00',
    new DateTimeZone('EST')
);

if ($d === false) {
    die("Incorrect date string");
} else {
    echo $d->getTimestamp();
}
```

**1222093305**

Or if you want to use [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). (Same as "[GMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time)".)

```
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat(
    'd-m-Y H:i:s',
    '22-09-2008 00:00:00',
    new DateTimeZone('UTC')
);

if ($d === false) {
    die("Incorrect date string");
} else {
    echo $d->getTimestamp();
}
```

**1222093289**

Regardless, it's always a good starting point to be strict when parsing strings into structured data. It can save awkward debugging in the future. Therefore I recommend to always specify date format.

Comment: Hey Falken, you are welcome. However it is probably better specifying that this solution applies to PHP 5.3+

Answer (score 45):

Using [mktime](http://php.net/mktime):

```
list($day, $month, $year) = explode('-', '22-09-2008');
echo mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year);
```

Comment: That's what I've always done. Explode it on - or / or . or whatever it's separated on, then mktime.

Comment: There is a note in the PHP manual for the last parameter of the mktime function: "As of PHP 5.1.0, this parameter became deprecated. As a result, the new timezone handling features should be used instead." I've yet to discover what the new features are that they speak about though, as they haven't linked to it!

Comment: This is far better than `strtotime()` For some reason `strtotime()` doesn't work on certain dates, and is therefore very unreliable.

Answer (score 20):

Using strtotime() function you can easily convert date to timestamp

```
<?php
// set default timezone
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

//define date and time
$date = date("d M Y H:i:s");

// output
echo strtotime($date);
?>
```

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Online conversion tool: http://freeonlinetools24.com/

Comment: To future readers - **strtotime()** was an accident and it's use should not be encouraged. It's ambiguous, because it tries to guess at the date format. Even if you use it correctly, it makes your code harder to understand and reason about and you run the risk of a change being made to your code base which will introduce errors, because no matter what you give to strtotime(), it will make it's best to guess. That guess may be incorrect, but you will get no indication it guessed incorrectly. It's a footgun. Use it if you like, but novice users can use a caveat I think. *Caution: footgun ahead*

Answer (score 14):

Here is a very simple and effective solution using the `split` and `mtime` functions:

```
$date="30/07/2010 13:24"; //Date example
list($day, $month, $year, $hour, $minute) = split('[/ :]', $date); 

//The variables should be arranged according to your date format and so the separators
$timestamp = mktime($hour, $minute, 0, $month, $day, $year);
echo date("r", $timestamp);
```

It worked like a charm for me.

Comment: Note that split() is now deprecated, but if you're using an ol' php version, it's working great!

Answer (score 7):

Use PHP function `strtotime()`

```
echo strtotime('2019/06/06');
```

[date — Format a local time/date](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_strtotime.asp)

Comment: he said, date to timestamp, not time to date

Comment: Check this now.

Answer (score 6):

If you know the format use `strptime` because `strtotime` does a guess for the format, which might not always be correct. Since `strptime` is not implemented in Windows there is a custom function

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php#86572

Remember that the returnvalue `tm_year` is from 1900! and `tm_month` is 0-11

Example:

```
$a = strptime('22-09-2008', '%d-%m-%Y');
$timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $a['tm_mon']+1, $a['tm_mday'], $a['tm_year']+1900)
```

Answer (score 6):

Given that the function `strptime()` does not work for Windows and `strtotime()` can return unexpected results, I recommend using `date_parse_from_format()`:

```
$date = date_parse_from_format('d-m-Y', '22-09-2008');
$timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $date['month'], $date['day'], $date['year']);
```

Comment: Note: with strtotime(): the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed. So I think don't need to use strptime()

Answer (score 6):

If you want to know for sure whether a date gets parsed into something you expect, you can use `DateTime::createFromFormat()`:

```
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', '22-09-2008');
if ($d === false) {
    die("Woah, that date doesn't look right!");
}
echo $d->format('Y-m-d'), PHP_EOL;
// prints 2008-09-22
```

It's obvious in this case, but e.g. `03-04-2008` could be 3rd of April or 4th of March depending on where you come from :)

Comment: `DateTime::createFromFormat` [returns `false` on error](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php#refsect1-datetime.createfromformat-returnvalues), not `null`.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php echo date('M j Y g:i A', strtotime('2013-11-15 13:01:02')); ?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 4):

```
$time = '22-09-2008';
echo strtotime($time);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I'd do it:

```
function dateToTimestamp($date, $format, $timezone='Europe/Belgrade')
{
    //returns an array containing day start and day end timestamps
    $old_timezone=date_timezone_get();
    date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
    $date=strptime($date,$format);
    $day_start=mktime(0,0,0,++$date['tm_mon'],++$date['tm_mday'],($date['tm_year']+1900));
    $day_end=$day_start+(60*60*24);
    date_default_timezone_set($old_timezone);
    return array('day_start'=>$day_start, 'day_end'=>$day_end);
}

$timestamps=dateToTimestamp('15.02.1991.', '%d.%m.%Y.', 'Europe/London');
$day_start=$timestamps['day_start'];
```

This way, you let the function know what date format you are using and even specify the timezone.

Answer (score 3):

```
function date_to_stamp( $date, $slash_time = true, $timezone = 'Europe/London', $expression = "#^\d{2}([^\d]*)\d{2}([^\d]*)\d{4}$#is" ) {
    $return = false;
    $_timezone = date_default_timezone_get();
    date_default_timezone_set( $timezone );
    if( preg_match( $expression, $date, $matches ) )
        $return = date( "Y-m-d " . ( $slash_time ? '00:00:00' : "h:i:s" ), strtotime( str_replace( array($matches[1], $matches[2]), '-', $date ) . ' ' . date("h:i:s") ) );
    date_default_timezone_set( $_timezone );
    return $return;
}

// expression may need changing in relation to timezone
echo date_to_stamp('19/03/1986', false) . '<br />';
echo date_to_stamp('19**03**1986', false) . '<br />';
echo date_to_stamp('19.03.1986') . '<br />';
echo date_to_stamp('19.03.1986', false, 'Asia/Aden') . '<br />';
echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s') . '<br />';

//1986-03-19 02:37:30
//1986-03-19 02:37:30
//1986-03-19 00:00:00
//1986-03-19 05:37:30
//2012-02-12 02:37:30
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php echo date('U') ?>
```

If you want, put it in a [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) input type timestamp. The above works very well (only in PHP 5 or later):

```
<?php $timestamp_for_mysql = date('c') ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

For PHP >=5.3, 7 & 8 the this may work-

```
$date = date_parse_from_format('%Y-%m-%d', "2022-11-15"); //here you can give your desired date in desired format. 
                                                           //just need to keep in mind that date and format matches.

$timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $date['month'], $date['day'], $date['year'] + 2000); //this will return the timestamp

$finalDate= date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp); //now you can convert your timestamp to desired dateTime format.
```

#### Docs:

- [`date_parse_from_format()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php)
- [`mktime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime)
- [`date()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date)

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the date in that format, you only need to call the "***strtotime***" function in PHP.

```
$date = '22-09-2008';
$timestamp = strtotime($date);
echo $timestamp; // 1222041600
```

Or in a single line:

```
echo strtotime('22-09-2008');
```

Short and simple.

Answer (score 0):

Please be careful about time/zone if you set it to save dates in database, as I got an issue when I compared dates from mysql that converted to `timestamp` using `strtotime`. you must use exactly same time/zone before converting date to timestamp otherwise, strtotime() will use default server timezone.

Please see this example: https://3v4l.org/BRlmV

```
function getthistime($type, $modify = null) {
    $now = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('Asia/Baghdad'));
    if($modify) {
        $now->modify($modify);
    }
    if(!isset($type) || $type == 'datetime') {
        return $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }
    if($type == 'time') {
        return $now->format('H:i:s');
    }
    if($type == 'timestamp') {
        return $now->getTimestamp();
    }
}
function timestampfromdate($date) {
    return DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date, new DateTimeZone('Asia/Baghdad'))->getTimestamp();
}

echo getthistime('timestamp')."--".
    timestampfromdate(getthistime('datetime'))."--".
    strtotime(getthistime('datetime'));

//getthistime('timestamp') == timestampfromdate(getthistime('datetime')) (true)
//getthistime('timestamp') == strtotime(getthistime('datetime')) (false)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this to get my timestamp.

```
$timestamp = strtotime("2020-05-03 04:30:55");
print_r($timestamp); or echo $timestamp;
```

Answer (score -1):

I have used this format:
$presentDateTime = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

Answer (score -4):

If you're looking to convert a UTC datetime (`2016-02-14T12:24:48.321Z`) to timestamp, here's how you'd do it:

```
function UTCToTimestamp($utc_datetime_str)
{
    preg_match_all('/(.+?)T(.+?)\.(.*?)Z/i', $utc_datetime_str, $matches_arr);
    $datetime_str = $matches_arr[1][0]." ".$matches_arr[2][0];

    return strtotime($datetime_str);
}

$my_utc_datetime_str = '2016-02-14T12:24:48.321Z';
$my_timestamp_str = UTCToTimestamp($my_utc_datetime_str);
```