# Converting human-friendly date to milliseconds

Tags: php, datetime

How to convert human-friendly date to milliseconds since the unix epoch?

Comment: dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113829/date-to-timestamp-php

Comment: If you take into account the _milliseconds_ issue it is not a dupe

Comment: It depends, to know that multiply seconds by 1k is not equal to have a milliseconds precision? see my answer :)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
strtotime($human_readable_date) * 1000
```

Comment: +1 for spotting he said milliseconds, which I didn't.

Comment: Note that you have milliseconds only as a fake, as your real precision is only of 1k milliseconds, aka second :) ... This way you __don't__ have milliseconds, but seconds expressed as number of milliseconds

Comment: loses microsecond precision

Answer (score 18):

Pay attention:
`strtotime() * 1000` is ok to have **seconds expressed as milliseconds!**

The right answer is that **it is not possible to have a millisecond precision on date/time functions in PHP**.
The precision of Unix Epoc based functions is only of 1k milliseconds, aka second :)

Using the suggested answers you don't have milliseconds, but **seconds expressed as number of milliseconds**.

If you are aware of this, and you don't really need a millisecond precision then the answers given are ok, but the question was wrong :)

Answer (score 15):

You're looking for [`strtotime`](http://us.php.net/strtotime).

Sample Usage:

```
$myvar = strtotime("7 October 2009");
```

That gives you seconds since the Unix epoch, so you want:

```
$myvar = strtotime("7 October 2009") * 1000;
```

Watch out for the fact that `strtotime` "guesses" what you mean (how should it interpret "12-08-2009"? probably as 8th December, but it might equally validly - and being a Brit, thoroughly sensibly - guess 12th August). If you know the format in advance, use [`strptime`](http://us.php.net/strptime).

Comment: This is a terrific answer as it also goes into detail on the date formatting. +1