# Convert date to milliseconds in laravel using Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

i make a date in laravel with carbon

```
$date = Carbon::createFromDate(2018,02,16);
```

how should i change it to milliseconds?

something like this:

```
18:16:30 -> 1532785457060
```

Comment: try this: strtotime($date) * 1000

Comment: This is the answer: strtotime($human_readable_date) * 1000 Try to make a search first. if don't found, then, you can put your question. Your question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532534/converting-human-friendly-date-to-milliseconds)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532534/converting-human-friendly-date-to-milliseconds

Answer (score 13):

For get the timestamp in milliseconds you can use

```
$date = Carbon::now();
$timeInMilliseconds = $date->valueOf()
```

As a alternate solution

```
 $timeInMilliseconds = $date->getPreciseTimestamp(3)
```

Comment: For reference, see [Getters](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-getters)

Answer (score 11):

It works, June, 2022.

```
now()->getTimestampMs()

// 1654259358879
```

Answer (score 7):

This works in `laravel 5.5` with `carbon 1`.

```
$timestamp = (int) round(now()->format('Uu') / pow(10, 6 - 3));
```

this is actually what `getPreciseTimestamp(3)` in `carbon2` does.

Comment: getPreciseTimestamp is only available on carbon 2, which laravel 5.5 doesn't have.

Answer (score 4):

You can convert any date. An example is below.

```
$dateWithMs = '2021-07-30 12:02:07.376000';

$timestamp = (int) round(Carbon::parse($date)->format('Uu') / pow(10, 6 - 3));
```

You should use Laravel >= 5.5 with Carbon 1.

It is working for me.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> $now = now();
=> Illuminate\Support\Carbon @1571283623 {#2987
     date: 2019-10-17 03:40:23.530274 UTC (+00:00),
   }
>>> $now->timestamp
=> 1571283623
>>> $x = $now->timestamp . $now->milli
=> "1571283623530"
>>> \Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimestampMs($x)->toDateTimeString()
=> "2019-10-17 03:40:23"
>>> >>> \Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimestampMs($x)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u')
=> "2019-10-17 03:40:23.530000"
```

Answer (score 3):

Takamura's answer is very close to being correct, but it contains a bug: you have to left pad the number with zeroes or you'll get the wrong answer if the current milliseconds are less than 100.

This example will give you the current time, in milliseconds:

```php
$carbon = now();

$nowInMilliseconds = (int) ($now->timestamp . str_pad($now->milli, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT));
```

To explain why you have to left pad the milliseconds a little bit more:

```
$seconds = 5;
$milliseconds = 75; // milliseconds are always between 0 and 999

// wrong answer: 575
$totalInMs = $seconds . $milliseconds; 

// correct answer: 5075
$totalInMs = $now->timestamp . str_pad($now->milli, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Answer (score -3):

You can do the following

```
$date = Carbon::createFromDate(2018,02,16); 

// 2018-02-16 15:43:38.617547 Europe/Berlin (+01:00)

$dateInMills = $date->timestamp;

// 1518792294
```

Comment: As @Keyur Mistry mentioned timestamp returns time in second, not in millisecond

Comment: It's the seconds, NOT milliseconds!