# How to convert a time to milliseconds using PHP

Tags: php, time, milliseconds

I need to convert a PHP time which is into milliseconds, I have tried using the "time * 1000" but the result is not correct.

example time: 01:26.7 (1 minute, 26 seconds, 7 milliseconds)

Comment: If you're trying to convert that literal string `01:26.7` you'll need to parse it first, you can't just multiply it because it's not a number

Comment: I'd expect https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php can help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to split the parts and convert every part to miliseconds then return the sum, something like:

```
$time1   = explode(":", "01:26.7");
$time2   = explode(".", $time1[1]);

$minute  = $time1[0] * 60 * 1000;
$second  = $time2[0] * 1000;
$milisec = $time2[1];

$result = $minute + $second + $milisec;

echo $result;
```

[**Live working example**](https://www.tehplayground.com/XqrJrpnCPEWNwfUw)

You can use `DateTime` class or a library for that, check:

[Convert date to milliseconds in laravel using Carbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51572004/convert-date-to-milliseconds-in-laravel-using-carbon)