# Calculate microseconds from now to a specific time in PHP

Tags: php

I noticed `usleep()` that can do something after a peroid of time. But I want this in a way that I have `execute` time, So to achive this with `usleep()` I need calculate the microseconds from now to the specific time.

For example: Now is 18:00:00.000 and I need to execute some tasks at 18:15:00.000 with a high accuracy like milliseconds or microseconds...

Any other good idea to do this OR how to calculate the difference between now and that time?

Answer (score 0):

Citing from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1532663/9226459)

> The right answer is that it is not possible to have a millisecond precision on date/time functions in PHP. The precision of Unix Epoc based functions is only of 1k milliseconds, aka second :)

So you cannot achieve milliseconds/microseconds accuracy in PHP