# PHP Convert Date into Milliseconds (ms)

Tags: php, date

How can I convert 01/01/2020-15:14 into milliseconds? It is driving me crazy. I tried using "d/m/Y-H:i" but I just can't get an output of milliseconds.

Comment: What do you mean "miliseconds"? Since when?

Comment: Convert to seconds, then multiply by 1000. Look into `mktime()` for conversion to seconds. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

Comment: try `strtotime("01/01/2020-15:14") * 1000`, check this post may helps you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532534/converting-human-friendly-date-to-milliseconds

Comment: Thank you! Sadly it does not work when I put in my $datearray instead of the string. It just shows 0. The array prints the same date strtotime($arr[1])

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to work with the [DateTime class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), which provides some interesting features. **Note**: PHP version >= 5.3

Use `$date->format('Uv');`

```
<?php
   $date = new DateTime('01/01/2020-15:14');
   $milliseconds = $date->format('Uv');
   echo $milliseconds;
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Still have a problem. I get the date out of a array. But when I put: $date = new DateTime($my_dt); in I get an error that I need a datetime object. So I tried. 
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y-H:i', $datefromarr[1]); 
 but this gives me the current datetime in ms.

Comment: $date = new DateTime("22/02/2022-12:12"); does not work
$date = new DateTime("02/22/2022-16:15"); does work
How do I get the first one working?

Comment: Okay fixed it. The array string had a newline at the end, which I could only see with var_dump(). FIxed it with: str_replace("\n", "", $arr[1]);