# Parsing localized date strings in PHP

Tags: php, localization

I have some code (it's part of a wordpress plugin) which takes a text string, and the format specifier given to date(), and attempts to parse it into an array containing hour, minute, second, day, month, year.

Currently, I use the following code (note that strtotime is horribly unreliable with things like 01/02/03)

```
// $format contains the string originally given to date(), and $content is the rendered string
if (function_exists('date_parse_from_format')) {
    $content_parsed = date_parse_from_format($format, $content);
} else {
    $content = preg_replace("([0-9]st|nd|rd|th)","\\1",$content);
    $content_parsed = strptime($content, dateFormatToStrftime($format));
    $content_parsed['hour']=$content_parsed['tm_hour'];
    $content_parsed['minute']=$content_parsed['tm_min'];
    $content_parsed['day']=$content_parsed['tm_mday'];
    $content_parsed['month']=$content_parsed['tm_mon'] + 1;
    $content_parsed['year']=$content_parsed['tm_year'] + 1900;
}
```

This actually works fairly well, and seems to handle every combination I've thrown at it.

However, recently someone gave me `24 Ноябрь, 2010`. This is Russian for November 24, 2010 [the date format was `j F, Y`], and it is parsed as year = 2010, month = null, day = 24.

Are there any functions that I can use that know how to translate both November and Ноябрь into 11?

EDIT:

Running `print_r(setlocale(LC_ALL, 0));` returns `C`. Switching back to `strptime()` seems to fix the problem, but the docs warn:

> Internally, this function calls the strptime() function provided by the system's C library. This function can exhibit noticeably different behaviour across different operating systems. The use of date_parse_from_format(), which does not suffer from these issues, is recommended on PHP 5.3.0 and later.

Is `date_parse_from_format()` the correct API, and if so, how do I get it to recognize the language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set the locale to Russian [as hinted in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php):

> Month and weekday names and other language dependent strings respect the current locale set with [`setlocale()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) `(LC_TIME`).

Comment: the problem is that it's a plugin that others might use... it would be nice to find a "proper" solution. But I think I'd just stick to `strptime()` until I find a case when it's not working...

Comment: @Mikeage A UnitTest is proper :) You can try if `date_create_from_format` can parse localized strings. I dont think it  does, but give it a try nonetheless.

Comment: I tried both strptime() and date_create_from_format to parse an italian date, like 18 Mag 2013 (= 2013-05-18) with no success.

Comment: @dam try the solutions offered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113829/how-to-convert-date-to-timestamp-in-php/6028533#6028533

Comment: @Gordon I had a chance to try but nope, I couldn't find any way to transform from Italian to English using IntlDateFormatter. It is possible from English to Italian though.

Basically using IntlDateFormatter: 
- from "2014-09-12" you can have "Set 12 2014" or "12 Set 2014" (these are Italian)

- from "Set 12 2014" or "12 Set 2014" you can't get to "2014-09-12". You need to translate "Set" to "Sep" first

Answer (score 1):

you could try take a locale parameter and call locale_set_default($locale) before doing the date parsing.

```
$originalLocale = locale_get_default();
$locale ? $locale : $originalLocale;
locale_set_default(locale);

// date parsing code

locale_set_default($originalLocale);
```

I haven't testing this but it's work a try.
FYI, I believe the locale string for Russian is "ru-Latn"

Comment: My problem is that I don't know what the locale is supposed to be, and I assume it's set already

Answer (score 0):

I see that the question is already answered but none of the solutions provided worked for me.

This is my solution:

```
if(!preg_match('/^en_US/', $locale)){

    $months_short = array('jan' => t('jan'), 'feb' => t('feb'), 'mar' => t('mar'), 'apr' => t('apr'),
            'may' => t('may'), 'jun' => t('giu'), 'jul' => t('lug'), 'aug' => t('ago'),
            'sep' => t('set'), 'oct' => t('ott'), 'nov' => t('nov'), 'dec' => t('dec'));

    foreach ($months_short as $month_short => $month_short_translated) {
        $date = preg_replace('/'.$month_short_translated.'/', $month_short, strtolower($date));
    }

}

$pieces = date_parse_from_format($format,$date);

if($pieces && $pieces['error_count'] == 0 && checkdate($pieces['month'], $pieces['day'], $pieces['year'])){

    return date('Y-m-d', mktime(0,0,0,$pieces['month'],$pieces['day'],$pieces['year'])); 

}
```

Where t() returns the translated abbreviation for the month.

Probably not the best solution ever (because it fails if there is no valid translation) but it works for my case.