# Parse Months In Russian

Tags: php, date

The have the following lines (the months are in Russian):

```
"Ноябрь 20 2012"
"Декабрь 19 2012"
"Сентябрь 12 2012"
"Июнь 5 2012"
"Август 2 2012"
```

I want to convert them to the following format:

```
11.20.2012
12.19.2012
09.12.2012
06.05.2012
08.02.2012
```

The problem, of course, is that the month is in Russian, so what I've tried doesn't work.

```
$date = "Ноябрь 20 2012";
print_r(date_parse_from_format("F j Y", $date));
```

How can I parse dates with Russian months?

Comment: Did you try `str_replace` the russian names with pre-made English names?

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand the question, but you might want to look into [strftime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php), [strtotime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), [setlocale](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php), and [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). Together, I think they should be able to do the trick.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do a workaround like this:

```
$ru_month = array( 'Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь' );
$en_month = array( 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December' );

print_r(date_parse_from_format("F j Y", str_replace($ru_month, $en_month, $date)));
```

---

PS: as others stated, there is a direct method, here is [a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655305/parsing-localized-date-strings-in-php) of your question.

Comment: But it's October, not Oktober :))

Comment: Also why did you forget about april... :'(

Comment: So, finally it would be:
$ru_month = array( 'Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь' );
$en_month = array( 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December' );

Answer (score 3):

first tell php to use your locale settings,

```
setlocale( LC_TIME, 'ru_RU', 'russian' );
```

then try to parse the string.

```
$date = "Ноябрь 20 2012";
print_r( date_parse_from_format("F j Y", $date) );
```

Comment: local settings have already been configured to "russian", I just received the Russian line, but thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `setlocale()` and `strftime()` for non-english dates