# How to convert the string french to datetime PHP

Tags: php, datetime

Is there anyway auto convert text time French become like d-m in PHP, example:

Aujourd'hui become 19-06

Hier become 18-06

17 juin become 17-06

I know use array and compare convert it to English like `strtotime('yesterday')` but would like to know have any other functional support auto convert it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing localized date strings in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655305/parsing-localized-date-strings-in-php)

Comment: Thanks, but sorry how to convert it when it is Hier, Aujourd'hui. Will check if else? Have anyway to do like `strtotime('Hier')`?

Comment: I don't think PHP will be able to translate that for you. That's named expressions for relative dates. http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php. I think you need to translate those words to English yourself before you can use them. It would be pain for PHP to be able to parse every combination in every language.

Answer (score 0):

```
      $date = '17 juin';
      $french_months = array('janvier', 'février', 'mars', 'avril', 'mai', 'juin', 'juillet', 'août', 'septembre', 'octobre', 'novembre', 'décembre');
      $months = array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');
      $date = str_replace($french_months, $months, strtolower($date));

      echo $date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date));
      echo "</br>";
      echo $date = date('d-m', strtotime($date))
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this one i know. Have any one other auto convert it?