# php date to timestamp

Tags: php, date, timestamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert date to timestamp in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113829/how-to-convert-date-to-timestamp-in-php)

I want to transfer some `date to timestamp` ,the date formart is `%day %month %time`. Like `25 nov 07:44`, I tried some method below, but the two dates are different. need a help, thanks.

```
<?php
$date = '25 nov 07:44';
$time = explode(" ",$date);
$minute = explode(":",$time[2]);
$timestamp = mktime(''.$minute[0].' '.$minute[1].' 00 '.$time[1].' '.$time[0].' 2011')."<br />";// mktime(%hour, %minute, %second, %month, %day, %year);
echo $timestamp; //1322202671
echo date("Y-m-j H:i:s", $timestamp); //2011-11-25 07:31:11
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In recent versions of php (5.3+), you can use `DateTime::createFromFormat()`.

Try something like

```
$format = 'd M H:i';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $timestamp);
echo $date->format('Y-m-j H:i:s');
```

Personally, I find this class based approach a little cleaner.

**PHP Docs**:

[`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

[`date()` for info on format strings](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: the new way is more easiler to call for use, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

A few problems:

- You are feeding `mktime` a string instead of a comma separated list
- `$time[1]` is a string and `mktime` needs a number for the month

You might want to give it a try with `strtotime` or otherwise add a translation table to go from your month strings to a number.

Comment: so what is the right `strtotime` formart for me? `"25-11-2011 07:44"`? so I shall make a str_replace for `nov` to `11`? Thanks.

Comment: @fish man see the manual for information about [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: Thanks for `strtotime`, `+1` ,but `DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $timestamp);` is a new way for me, a php starter, also not quite know the new method in `php5.3+`

Comment: @fish man I agree; unfortunately I'm limited to php5.2 for most of my projects...

Comment: @jeroen, so do I, I updated my php version to new, but my text book is `php5.1`.