# PHP and or mysql: Make a date from some variables

Tags: php, mysql

Assume that i have two variables in php:

```
$year
$month
```

Then I want to make another variable:

```
$date
```

which:

```
$date=$year-$month-25
```

So, if I have 2012 in $year and 7 for $month, $date will be 2012-07-25.

Actually, I will compare it with some date in MySQL.
$year and $month are inputted by user.

anybody have a solution?
The solution either how to make $date or anything as long it can be comparred with a date in mysql.
Thanks before. ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a unix timestamp through this:

```
$myDate = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 25, $year);
```

This is a pretty useful thing to have, as you can format it into all sorts of nice via:

```
echo date("Y-m-d", $myDate);
// Prints something like: 2012-07-25
```

or

```
echo date("l", $myDate);
// Prints something like: Monday
```

or

```
date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A', $myDate);
// Prints something like: Monday 8th of August 2005 03:12:46 PM
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follows

```
$complete_date = $year."-".$month."-25";
```

which gives you 2012-7-25

Comment: These dates are not easily comparable to MySQL dates in PHP, you need to convert to a timestamp first so integer comparison (which is reliable can occur)

Comment: thanks.
can comparison between $complete_date and a date type in mysql give a correct ressult? ^^

Answer (score 1):

Please, read the "[php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)" for concat your PHP string.

it's not

```
$date = $year-$month-25;
```

it is

```
$date = $year . '-' . $month . '- 25';
```

or

```
$date = $year . "-" . $month . "- 25";
```

but simple quote is more optimize for php string.

Comment: you want just compare two date? ahhh, OKay, you want to convert all date in Timestamp, after, you can find difference between your two Timestamp (read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113829/how-to-convert-date-to-timestamp-in-php) for more details in timestamp) and convert difference in days, or month, or all what you want ^^

Answer (score 1):

> The solution either how to make $date or anything as long it can be
>   comparred with a date in mysql

The key here is use of `strtotime` to create and compare.

MySQL dates can be converted to integer through the use of strototime:

```
strtotime($mysql_date);
```

Then you can get `time()` and compare to two:

```
time()<>strtotime($mysql_date) // then the two dates are not equal.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use mktime function

```
$date = date('Y-m-d',mktime(0,0,0,$month,25,$year));
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would use mktime to get the timestamp of the date ( http://php.net/manual/de/function.mktime.php ) and use the command unix_timestamp(date(yourfield)) in mysql to compare them.
(the date() withing unix_timestamp is only required when you save datetime values and not pure date values)

Answer (score 1):

Since mysql dates are usually in this format `Y-m-d` by default, you can use

```
$thedate = date('Y-m-d',mktime(0,0,0,$month,25,$year));
```

where `$month` and `$year` are based on the user input. Of course you have to make the user input it in the format you want by using select/lists.