# Expiration of Memcache objects on specific date

Tags: python, memcached

I would like to set the expiry time for memcache objects to a specific date.

```
cache.set(string, 1, 86400)
```

The statement above allows me to set it for a day, but it does not expire if the date changes. One way I could handle this is by calculating the number of seconds left in the day and provide it as a variable.

I was wondering if there was a more simpler/efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/clientclass#Client_set), we see that the expiration parameter is explained as:

> Optional expiration time, either relative number of seconds from current time (up to 1 month), or an absolute Unix epoch time. By default, items never expire, though items may be evicted due to memory pressure. Float values will be rounded up to the nearest whole second.

So basically if the number you put in there is less than 2592000, it is interpreted as a *relative* time.  So the number 86400 would be interpreted as 86400 seconds (one day) from *now*, the time it's being set.

It looks like you're going to want to use a number bigger than that to signify an *absolute* time.  There are a [variety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113829/how-to-convert-date-to-timestamp-in-php) of ways to get a unix timestamp.  But quite simply you can do:

```
time_tuple = (2013, 2, 15, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0)
timestamp = time.mktime(time_tuple)
cache.set(string, 1, timestamp);
```

You initial idea is correct.  You can find out the timestamp for now, and the timestamp of the date you want and just provide the difference, that would be equivalent too.

Answer (score 0):

The day changes at least every hour of every day, does it not?  Either the client or the server must specify which one of those is relevant to any given request.  This is generally a better task for the client application.

Do note that you can specify absolute timestamps, which might make it easier to calculate when that expiry time is since you'd be able to reuse it for the whole day (or at least an hour).

Comment: Exactly, I would like to specify absolute timestamp to midnight GMT while I set the object in memcache. I was not successful in finding the syntax for the same. Appreciate if you could share. Thanks.