# Convert Data in timestamp

Tags: php, date

I have a data in my input text example: `07/22/2013 17:32` and I would like convert in timestamp for inset in my database how can i do?

Myabe the function is `mktime` but I don't know how use it.

I'm waiting for help thank you very much

Comment: There is a [manual](http://www.php.net/) that answers this kind of questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) like,

```
echo $timestamp=strtotime('07/22/2013 17:32');
```

Possible Duplicate of [How to convert date to timestamp in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113829/how-to-convert-date-to-timestamp-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP's [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
$timestamp = strtotime('07/22/2013 17:32');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [strtotime](https://www.php.net/strtotime) to convert the text string into a Unix timestamp.
From there, you can use [date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to reformat the timestamp as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Most other answers are suggesting doing it in PHP with strtotime, but that's a silly option. It'll involve at least TWO format conversion (string -> int -> string), and there's also the danger of multiple timezone conversions coming into play and mangling your date before it ever gets saved into the table.

You can do it in MySQL directly, as a single string->native conversion:

```
INSERT INTO foo (datetimefield)
    VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('07/22/2013 17:32', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i'));
```

Ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date