# php - Convert month number to month short name while I am calling it from Mysqli

Tags: php

I am calling the data from Mysqli and in my table it appear like this 2012-10-05 I need to call it near my new to be display like this `<span class="date"><strong>28</strong><span>may</span></span>` no I have two values one is the day and the other is month
and also I'd like it to appear as number for day and short name for month eg.Feb May

this is my PHP code

```
<?php
    $getNews="SELECT * FROM news";
    $QgetNews=$db->query($getNews)or die($db->error);
?>
```

Comment: @Andy that will give him a numeric month, no? He still needs to convert it to a named one

Comment: @MarkBaker I am using date type

Comment: Use `DATE_FORMAT`: `SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2013-12-19', '%b') as month`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) for that.

```
<?php
// $QgetNews->date = 10-05-2012
echo date('d M, Y', strtotime($QgetNews->date)); // 10 May, 2012
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/0Z7wVSL5)

Comment: that is fine @Chen Asraf but how to division them on my style <span class="date"><strong>**28**</strong><span>**may**</span></span> and I need to get just the day and month no need for year

Answer (score 0):

Im not 100% sure how your data looks but if it's 2012-10-05 like you say then check out [Converting date to timestamp in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113829/how-to-convert-date-to-timestamp-in-php)

Then take that timestamp and feed into date() or a shorter version:
    $month = date("M", strtotime($date));

which will return the shortname of the month. Look at [PHP Manual Date()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for more of the parameters that can be used to get the day, year etc... You can call each one individually like in my example, or you could comma separate and explode the variable into an array if you really wanted.