# Get date from database in php

Tags: php, mysql

i am storing date and time in database using php using gmdate() function in format "Y-m-d H:i:s". for e.g.

```
2014-03-10 12:35:55
```

Now,on getting this data into a php variable,for e.g.

```
$temp=2014-03-10 12:35:55
```

can i extract and display only the DATE portion excluding the TIME portion??
I am new to date and time manipulation.Any help?

Comment: Why not using Time, Date, Year in seperate coloumn $date = date('d');
$month = date('m');
$year = date('Y');

Comment: you can try this date('Y:m:d', strtotime($temp));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can get directly the date from database like this

```
select DATE(column_datetime) as date from yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime($temp));
```

The above statement returns the date from datetime format

Comment: This won't work because `date` is expecting an integer UNIX timestamp as second argument: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: As secelite told it takes UNIX timestamp, try the updated one now, it is simple

Comment: Never heard of DateTime class that lets you create a DateTime object using arbitrary format? I won't downvote you but using explode... it's just bad.

Comment: @N.B. I have changed my answer

Answer (score 0):

As Pramod answered,

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime($temp));
```

works.

Comment: A little note to that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113829/how-to-convert-date-to-timestamp-in-php#115864

Comment: its not safe to use strtotime but strptime is not available for windows.whats the solution now?

Answer (score 0):

The following code example is adapted by this thread: [How to convert date to timestamp in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113829/how-to-convert-date-to-timestamp-in-php)

There you can also read why it is not safe to rely on `strtotime` (answer by daremon)

```
$temp = '2014-03-10 12:35:55';
$a = strptime($temp, '%Y-%m-%d');
$timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $a['tm_mon']+1, $a['tm_mday'], $a['tm_year']+1900);
```

**Edit**

From the PHP manual

> Note: This function is not implemented on Windows platforms.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

Echo date('Y-M-D', $var);