# Manipulating Strings Using PHP

Tags: php

Currently I have a date in the format: 04/07/2014, (4/7/2014) I need to change this so that it is: 07/04/2014 so I can convert it to a time stamp using: $time1 = strtotime("dd/mm/yy"); I am doing this so I can compare multiple dates.
How can I do this using php?

Comment: Why don't you just do a `$time1 = strtotime("mm/dd/yy");` ?

Comment: If you just need to get a timestamp, use [date_create_from_format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Comment: Is 04/07/2014 in DD/MM/YYYY or MM/DD/YYYY?

Comment: Is "04/07/2014" a string or a `date`?

Comment: "04/07/14" is a string and in the format:  MM/DD/YYYY

Comment: I may be misunderstanding this command, @arkascha could I do       $date= strtotime("mm/dd/yy"); (assuming $date is 04/07/14)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is simple function:

```
<?php

function format_date($dateToConvert) {

    return date('d/m/Y', strtotime($dateToConvert));
}

$date = "04/07/14";

echo format_date($date);
```

Output: `07/04/2014`

[LIVE DEMO](http://3v4l.org/krGH4#v430)

Comment: Thankyou, concise and well written, allowing for quick and efficient implementation.

Comment: Do you know how I could convert this date to a timestamp?

Comment: read this-> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113829/how-to-convert-date-to-timestamp-in-php