# Convert date into timestamp where strtotime has already been used

Tags: php, date

I' am trying to convert the date of next 7 days into timestamp so that I can compare against my date timestamp in database to get some results.

**This function is used to get the next 7 days from today**

```
$next_date = date("d/m/Y", strtotime("7 day"))
```

**Output**

```
30/04/2014
```

Now I' am again running strtotime() on $next_date variable who holds the next 7days and converting to timestamp.

```
echo strtotime($next_date);
```

This is not working. I followed this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113829/how-to-convert-date-to-timestamp-in-php) answer and few others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative suggestion you could look at PHP's internal `DateTime()` and `DateInterval()` classes. It makes it a bit easier to convert between formats and do date/time addition and subtraction imho. `DateInterval` requires at least PHP version 5.3.

An example:

```
// create a current DateTime
$currDate = new DateTime();

// copy the current DateTime and
// add an interval of 7 days
$nextDate = clone $currDate;
$nextDate->add(new DateInterval('P7D'));

// both objects are easily converted to timestamps
echo $currDate->getTimestamp(); // e.g: 1398296728
echo $nextDate->getTimestamp(); // e.g: 1398901528

// and both can be easily formatted in other formats
echo $currDate->format('d/m/Y'); // e.g: 24/04/2014
echo $nextDate->format('d/m/Y'); // e.g: 01/05/2014
```

**EDIT**

For completeness, here's another example of how you can add seven days to a `DateTime` object:

```
$now  = new DateTimeImmutable();
$then = $now->modify('+7 days');

var_dump($now->format('Y-m-d'), $then->format('Y-m-d'));
```

Yields:

```
string(10) "2016-05-24"
string(10) "2016-05-31"
```

You can also use `DateTime` - the difference in this use case is that `DateTime::modify()` will modify the instance `$now` where `DateTimeImmutable::modify()` will return a new `DateTimeImmutable` object - so if you need to create a new object whilst retaining the old one, it's probably the most succinct approach.

Hope this helps :)

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php

Answer (score 2):

Just store the value from strtotime first?

```
$timestamp_in_7_days = strtotime('7 day');
$next_date = date('d/m/Y', $timestamp_in_7_days);
```

There is no need to throw the time back and forth between unix timestamp and date-format.

Comment: Indeed.  I just wanted to add, the poster said "it did not work".  I'm guessing the problem is that you made $next_date formatted d/m/Y, and according to PHP's manual: `Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.
To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible.`

Comment: @Kai - Yes, that is correct. He could make it work by splitting up the string, using mktime or something, but this is the cleanest approach as I see it ;)

Comment: Yep, I would have said that approach myself if you hadn't beaten me to it.  =)