# convert time to Unix Time stamp

Tags: php, datetime, time, datetime-conversion

I need to convert the following date in to Unix format using php code.

`2014-06-10T11:05:10.723Z` to Unix?

Comment: try to find you have many way

Comment: There was a mistake in the question i need to convert in to Unix time stamp.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert date to timestamp in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113829/how-to-convert-date-to-timestamp-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this has so many downvotes is it takes a single in-built function to change a Date to a timestamp, using a single Google search to find.

```
echo strtotime("2014-06-10T11:05:10.723Z");
```

Outputs:

```
1402398310
```

Comment: There was a mistake in the question i need to convert in to Unix time stamp.

Comment: Then just use strtotime from my example, delete the rest.
`strtotime("2014-06-10T11:05:10.723Z")`