# What is this date format? 1425624506986

Tags: php, xml, datetime

I've been stuck with this date format.

1425624506986 = Mar 6, 2015 08:48:26

I have lots of data to convert but I don't know which format is this.

For example, how can I change this format:

"2015.07.09 20:23" to like this "1425624506986" (Theese are examples, they are not the same date value)

Could help me to figure this out?

Thanks

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113829/how-to-convert-date-to-timestamp-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unix time with ms. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

You use `date("d.m.Y", intval(1425624506986/1000));` for convert in dd.mm.YYY
`1425624506986/1000 = Fri, 06 Mar 2015 06:48:26 GMT`