# How do I set " 2015-10-06T15:39:07-05:00 " this kind of timestamp in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, timestamp

I have to covert my current time stamp in above mentioned format. How do I do it using PHP and what 'T' means in above statement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert date to timestamp in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113829/how-to-convert-date-to-timestamp-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function with `c` ISO 8601 date (added in PHP 5)

Simple:

```
<?php
echo date("c");
```

Comment: Yoo!! Got it.. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have not given us your current timestamp, but you can echo the mentioned timestamp like this:

```
echo Date("Y-m-d"). "T" .date("h:i:s-O");
```

I believe T means time. But don't know

Comment: This wouldn't give the addtional -5:00 according to the time zone.

Comment: @Object Manipulator Did not see that