# PHP Comparing Current Date to a Given Date

Tags: php, date

I am having a hard time getting a simple date check to work properly. I searched all the questions, and so far none of the solutions have helped me.

I want to do a loop from a certain date, until today.

What is currently happening with the below code is that its not stopping and just keeps going. When I log i, I can see the date is increasing by a day like it should. I also  tried flipping the operator to <, but that caused the loop to be skipped entirely.

Any ideas?

```
$startOfPlayoffs = new DateTime( "2016-04-29" );
$today = date("Y-m-d");

        for($i = $startOfPlayoffs; $i >= $today; $i->modify('+1 day'))
        {
         //... some stuff
        }
```

Interestingly, when I hard-code the date, it works fine. I.E:

```
$endOfPlayoffs  = new DateTime( "2016-05-02" );
```

That isn't ideal, so was hoping to get it to work properly.

Comment: Initialize `$today` as a `DateTime` object.  As it is, it's just a string

Comment: check that date format is returning a string comparable with your start date...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing a PHP Date object ($startOfPlayoffs) with a string ($today). Try converting $today into a Date object:

```
$startOfPlayoffs = new DateTime("2016-04-29");
$today = new DateTime();
$cpt = 0;
for($i = $startOfPlayoffs; $i <= $today; $i->modify('+1 day')){
    echo time($i) . "<br>";
    if ($cpt++ >= 100) exit;// as a safeguard
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use [unix time stamps](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php), they are concrete numbers that are much easier to deal with.

```
int time(void) //current time stamp
```

You can also use `strtotime()` to convert [date strings into time stamps](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113829/how-to-convert-date-to-timestamp-in-php) for conversion from numbered date formats to unix timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `->diff()` method of the DateTime class like this is quite clean

The `->diff()` method produces an DateInterval Object that looks like this

```
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 3
    [d] => 4
    [h] => 17
    [i] => 23
    [s] => 4
    [weekday] => 0
    [weekday_behavior] => 0
    [first_last_day_of] => 0
    [invert] => 0
    [days] => 95
    [special_type] => 0
    [special_amount] => 0
    [have_weekday_relative] => 0
    [have_special_relative] => 0
)
```

So the code can be as simple as this

```
<?php
    $startOfPlayoffs = new DateTime( "2016-01-29" );
    $today= new DateTime();
    $diff = $startOfPlayoffs ->diff($today);

    for ( $i = 0; $i<$diff->days; $i++ ) {

         // do stuff
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use: `date_format($startOfPlayoffs,"Y-m-d")` to obtain a "variable" you can compare against...

```
$startOfPlayoffs = new DateTime( "2016-04-29" );
$today = date("Y-m-d");

    for($i = date_format($startOfPlayoffs,"Y-m-d"); $i >= $today; $i->modify('+1 day'))
    {
     //... some stuff
    }
```