# yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz to timestamp php convertion

Tags: php

what is the php command for convert this this date and time format 2016-09-15T16:00:00Z format to timestamp (example:  1490313600) ?

Comment: Use `strtotime()`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891937/strtotime-doesnt-work-with-dd-mm-yyyy-format

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert date to timestamp in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113829/how-to-convert-date-to-timestamp-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Its a `strtotime()`

1.[reference1](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_strtotime.asp)

2.[reference2](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
 <?php
echo strtotime("2016-09-15T16:00:00Z");
?>
```

***ouput***

```
1473955200
```

Comment: isnt possible to do conversion with this type of code ?  [strtotime(2016-09-15T16:00:00Z)]

Comment: No its possible to convert.i was added code see my answer.and i was also check with my localhost.Its working

Comment: error occured from the output  Warning: date() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in xxxxxx

Comment: @JackLiew Can you tell what you are expecting?In this part code working fine for me