# Passing value of HTML datetime-local input into php variable formatted as timestamp

Tags: php, html, datetime, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I'm trying to get the value from an HTML datetime-local input into a PHP variable as a timestamp.

Here is the HTML:

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="_gaddon_setting_date_time" value="2017-11-24T10:00" class="gaddon-setting gaddon-datetime-local" id="date_and_time_of_export">
```

Here is the PHP I am trying to use to get this value into a variable as a timestamp:

```
$date_and_time_field = mktime($form['autoexport_csv_addon']['date_and_time_of_export']);
```

$form is the object that this class can use to grab the value of the forms inputs.

The value is turned into a timestamp, but it is setting the time for January 26th, 2018 at 01:27:36 when the time selected is actually November 24th, 2017 at 10:00:00. Does anyone know why the datetime-local value isn't formatting properly for a timestamp conversion? Thanks very much!

Comment: These may help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113829/how-to-convert-date-to-timestamp-in-php
http://php.net/datetime.formats

Comment: Thank you!!! strtotime() did the trick!

Comment: Also be mindful with timezones, and what the php server timezone is set too. The value example you show doesnt include timezone offset, so it may still drift from expected.