Modify string from one column before inserting into another
I have imported a CSV file into mysql 5.7 and need to modify the date so that I can manage it later.
The imported data is currently in a column called localDate which needs to be modified. It looks like this:

Mon Jun 24 2024 17:12:18 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

I already have the PHP code to put the date how I need it:
// extract date from string.
  $original_date =  substr($row['localDate'], 3,12);
// convert to yyyy-mm-dd
  $local_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($original_date)); 


2024-06-24

Basically I just need to know how to copy from the localDate column to the new local_date column while updating the date using my variable name $local_date

Presumably you are then inserting the contents of $row into the database after this? If so then just assign a new array key like in any other PHP array, e.g. $row["local_date"] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($original_date)). Then your later code can use that data during the SQL insert operation. That's assuming you want it in a new column called "local_date". In one place in the post you say you want to write to a new local_date column, but earlier in the post you said you wanted to modify the existing localDate column.

I would not use substr. The PHP datetime functions can handle this for you as is.

possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/6028533/208809

Sorry for the confusion. I want to get the data from localDate, modify to yyyy-mm-dd, then insert the newly formatted date into the local_date column

Import using input preprocessing, convert the value from CSV to proper format with STR_TO_DATE() and save this converted value.

@Ronaldo my first comment should be sufficient then? Unless there's some aspect you haven't informed us about

Why do this in PHP? Do it in SQL: UPDATE tablename SET local_date = STR_TO_DATE(localDate, '<format string>')

I agree with barmar. Doing this procedurally in a loop to issue all those UPDATE statements is going to be slow even on a small table. Here's how to do this in mysql directly: https://dbfiddle.uk/XlLjW0fP

@JNevill  you are correct. Your solution is way better. Thank you.  Please post as an answer so that I can mark it as answered

Time for a [tag:mysql] badger to do some serious heap curation: Related content: Importing a CSV to MySQL with different date format and MySQL CSV import: datetime value and Import date from csv file as DATE format in MySQL database and CSV date format to MySQL date format and MySql Workbench csv Import Datetime DATATYPE as TEXT

and MySQL How To Upload CSV dates from 'mm/dd/yyyy' directly into a DATE data type format and import CSV to MySQL and convert date and How to change string date to MySQL date format at time of import of CSV using MySQL's LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE and MySQL Import CSV, Convert Date Format - Best Practice

and MySQL Workbench - Table Data Import Wizard writing all datetime objects as 0000-00-00 00:00:00 and Import csv mysql with multiple custom date formats and import csv with date to mysql through php and Change date format while loading with LOAD IN DATA FILE and my csv import is not formatting the dates

and In MYSQL, how to upload a csv file that contains a date in the format of '1/1/2020' properly into a DATE data type format (standard YYYY-MM-DD) and MySQL - Importing CSV file with USA DateTime format: "4/18/2017 22:15" and How to import data.csv file to phpmyadmin(mysql) having columns with datetime format? and Import CSV to SQL - Date format issues: Zeroes

As mentioned in the comments by @Barmar and me, doing updates in a loop is generally a bad idea because every update has to be shoved across the wire to your database. Even on a small table this will be a slow solution. Instead, adding this new column and running a single update statement will be much faster.
CREATE TABLE imported_csv (id int, localDate VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO imported_csv VALUES (1, 'Mon Jun 24 2024 17:12:18 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)'), (2, 'Tue Jun 25 2024 13:22:44 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)');

ALTER TABLE imported_csv ADD COLUMN local_date DATE;

/*One update statement to update all records*/
UPDATE imported_csv
SET local_date = STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING(localDate, 5, 11), "%M %d %Y");

SELECT * FROM imported_csv;


+-----------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|                         localDate                         | local_date |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Mon Jun 24 2024 17:12:18 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) | 2024-06-24 |
| Tue Jun 25 2024 13:22:44 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) | 2024-06-25 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+------------+

https://dbfiddle.uk/XlLjW0fP
A good rule of thumb is that if you find yourself solving a problem by running sql (any sql) in a loop, there is likely a better set-based way of solving it.

You're probably on the right track. But i don't think there is any need of substr function. PHP can handle this in better way.
$original_date = "Mon Jun 24 2024 17:12:18 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)";
$dateString = preg_replace('/\s+GMT.*$/', '', $original_date); // it will remove timezone related information from the string
$local_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($dateString));

Passing the string containing timezone will throw exception. Instead let you extract the datetime information from it.
Using substr is not a good way, What if in feature you will have more chars then 12? At that time your logic will failed to parse the datetime.

Because the sought leading portion of the date time expression has a predictable length, it is too much work to implement a regex technique.  substr() is much more ideal in this case. Perhaps even better than that, use a legitimate datetime parser and then format the parsed value as desired.
